# Cannot invoke method last() on null object in soap ui

Tags: soap, groovy

I am new to soap ui. I am trying to fetch list of files using groovy and trigger the soap UI for the same files. groovy script us running fine.but in request I am getting response stating that "Cannot invoke method last() on null object".Am I missing something:

Here is my groovy script:

```
def fileList = []

File theInfoName = new File("D:\\SOAP")
theInfoName.eachFile { file ->
if (file.isFile() && file.name.endsWith('.txt')) {
  fileList.add(file) 
}
}
  log.info fileList
//context.put('fileList', fileList)
```

Here is my request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
        ${=new File("D:\\SOAP\\" + (context.get('fileList')).last()).text}
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

but when I see in request messageExchangeResults it is showing:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
        Cannot invoke method last() on null object
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: why is there a commentary on the line `//context.put` ?

Comment: if I uncomment this in requestExchangeMessage shown like this:

Comment: <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
  Could not find matching constructor for: java.io.File(java.io.File)   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

Comment: This last error is not coherent with the code you wrote

Comment: `context.get('fileList')` is the property you put in `context.put('fileList'..)` : a collection of files. last() return the last element of the collection: a File. You are constructing a new File by concatenating "d://soap" with this file (can't work, but not with the error you see - the filename is just invalid)

Comment: ohk..I got now I removed "D://SOAP" .it is just written "(context.get('fileList')).last()).text",I apologize I for I forgot to mention